# Override autocomplete provided by module to not suggest current user(self)

Tags: 7, ajax, privatemsg

I hope it's pretty clear from my question title itself. I want to override autocomplete provided by module such as [privatemessage](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) to not suggest the current user(self) who is trying to send message.
I tried doing some research about it but all I got was about overriding JS file.

I have used automcomplete with my custom form long ago & when I prepared the JSON, I removed current user from the list. But what to do if I have to do the same for some contributed module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working code

> - Add this to your custom module
> - Replace MYMODULENAME with your custom module name

```
function MYMODULENAME_query_privatemsg_autocomplete_alter($query) {
  global $user;
  $query->condition('u.uid', $user->uid, '<>');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Error "An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: http://localhost/alpha/messages/autocomplete
StatusText: Internal Server Error
ResponseText:

Comment: I have the same code setup working on my local.I am not able to reproduce the error on my side.
I assume you have reverted the changes you made else where before trying this snippet and after implementing this hook you cleared the cache

Comment: I think it's working now as I am not getting any ajax error and it suggest only other names :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the code in [Privatemsg](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module, the autocomplete callback function provides a hook [hook_privatemsg_autocomplete_alter()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!privatemsg!privatemsg.api.php/function/hook_privatemsg_autocomplete_alter/7). You can use this hook and unset the current logged in user from the `$matches` array.

I don't have Privatemsg module installed in any of my current projects, so I cannot test it, but the following code should do it:

```
function YOURMODULE_privatemsg_autocomplete_alter(&$matches, $names, $fragment) {
  global $user;
  unset($matches[$user->uid]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it still populate global user.

Comment: @RajeevK is this hook ever called? What's in `$matches` in it?

Comment: @Mołot - Yes its called & I got user_1 & user_10 stdClass object with all their info once I DPM it..

Comment: @RajeevK are they indexed by their uids in array? And are you taking it by reference for sure?

Comment: @Mołot - They are indexed separately by UID. What do you mean by reference here ?

Comment: @RajeevK is there `&$matches` or simply `$matches` in your function definition? First one says you want to edit original array in your function. Second option means you are editing a copy and your edit will not affect anything outside your function.

Comment: @Mołot - I have &$matched in my function definition & then unset($matches[$user->uid]); inside the function after fetching global $user;

Comment: @RajeevK read your comment again ;) $matched and $matches are different variables. choose one name and stick with it ;) I suggest to keep **s** there.

Comment: @Mołot - Sorry for it, that was typos but at my function I have used $matches. I think the other solution is working as now it's not giving me ajax error..